# Nested Query with Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How can I retrieve data where I want to write a nested query with joins?
I want to display `first_name`, `designation` from `t1`, and display `project_name`, `col2` from `t2` where `end_date= (select max(end_date) from project where res_id=?)`;

Can you please help me to write the sql query

```
select R.first_name, R.Designation, R.DOB, R.DOJ, R.Department, 
R.city, p.project_name, p.start_date, p.end_date, 
p.end_date+1 as next_avail_date 
from resources R full JOIN project p on (r.res_id=p.res_id) 
where r.u_id='&u_id';
```

I want to select project name based on the following query

```
select project_name from project where end_date= (select max(end_date) from project where res_id=1);
```

how do I add it in the above query?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: select R.first_name, R.Designation, R.DOB, R.DOJ, R.Department, 
R.city, p.project_name, p.start_date, p.end_date, 
p.end_date+1 as next_avail_date from resources R full JOIN project p on (r.res_id=p.res_id) where r.u_id='&u_id'; I want to select project_name from project where end_date= (select max(end_date) from project where res_id=1);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query as a view into the FROM CLAUSE and do join with it same way like a table. Try with something like this

```
select R.first_name, 
       R.Designation, 
       R.DOB, R.DOJ, 
       R.Department, 
       R.city,     
       p.project_name, 
       p.start_date, 
       p.end_date, 
       p.end_date+1 as next_avail_date 
  from resources r, (select project_name 
                       from project 
                      where end_date= (select max(end_date) 
                                         from project pr 
                                        where pr.res_id=1)) p
 where r.u_id='&u_id'
   and r.res_id=p.res_id;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error ORA-00904: "P"."RES_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 15 Column: 17